# A better pattern to handle growing up if condition with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to judge every input string if it matches the rule.

So in this block, the code will be changed or increased frequently,

What's the good pattern to solve this problem, to keep my code from too lengthy

```
if re.match("(exposurewin_c)(.*?)(_profile_i)", input_str):              
    DO SOMETHING

if re.match("....", input_str):              
    DO SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if the segment of code to be executed as per a condition can be long, it should be moved to its own function that takes some arguments and then return the calculated value (or a tuple of values) - this allow them to be tested individually, and may be relocated to alternative modules.

Second, use [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) to return a "compiled" regular expression object to save some computational time per execution, especially if the process may be long lived or if you got many regular expressions to match.

Finally, you may consider sticking all that into a list of 2-tuple and use a `for` loop to go through all the conditions.  I've done something similar before, and this might get you started.
    import re

```
def action_exposure(match, input_str):
    # do something with the match result
    print("exposure caught")
    print(match.groups())

def action_process(match, input_str):
    # do something with the match result
    print("process caught")
    print(match.groups())


raw = [
    ('^exposure:(?P<suffix>[0-9]*)', action_exposure),
    ('^process:(?P<suffix>[0-9]*)', action_process),
]

# compile the raw expression
compiled = [(re.compile(p), f) for p, f in raw]


inputs = """
exposure:3
process:35
somethingelse:3333
exposure:4
"""

for i in inputs.splitlines():
    for regexp, f in compiled:
        match = regexp.match(i)
        if not match:
            continue
        f(match, i)

import re

def action_exposure(match, input_str):
    # do something with the match result
    print("exposure caught")
    print(match.groups())

def action_process(match, input_str):
    # do something with the match result
    print("process caught")
    print(match.groups())


raw = [
    ('^exposure:(?P<suffix>[0-9]*)', action_exposure),
    ('^process:(?P<suffix>[0-9]*)', action_process),
]

# compile the raw expression
compiled = [(re.compile(p), f) for p, f in raw]


inputs = """
exposure:3
process:35
somethingelse:3333
exposure:4
"""

for i in inputs.splitlines():
    for regexp, f in compiled:
        match = regexp.match(i)
        if not match:
            continue
        f(match, i)
```

Running that, you can see how the script executes

```
exposure caught
('3',)
process caught
('35',)
exposure caught
('4',)
```

Once you got this pattern down you can simply just define functions to do that one thing that satisfies your condition, then compose the pattern (or condition) and add that to the list of `raw` definitions.  Also, this will allow much more code reuse since you can define multiple conditions to execute the function (in the case where regex is hard).

Also, do note that I made some assumptions on what is done - you do need to do some work into deciding how/what arguments you want to pass into the functions as that generally needs to remain consistent, however when you break the problem down like this it will make it easier to think about and get you to your solutions faster.